# PHP PECL / make: How to pass extra arguments to PHP "make test" script?

Tags: php, makefile, configure, pecl

The standards build process for PHP PECL ext looks like this:

```
./configure
make
make test
```

But my enviroment has globally disabled `proc_open` via `disable_functions`, so the `make test` command fails with:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|                       ! ERROR !                           |
| The test-suite requires that proc_open() is available.    |
| Please check if you disabled it in php.ini.               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
Makefile:134: recipe for target 'test' failed
```

How can I fix this in locally WITHOUT changing the global php.ini file? Is is possible to pass some arguments to the `php` executable (or to the `configure` that pass it later) via enviroment variables?

Comment: `php -n` will run PHP without loading any INI file and `php -c <file>` will run it with a specific file.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Yes, but how to pass these arguments to the `make test` command?

Comment: If you can modify the makefile itself, some other ini settings are passed in the `PHP_TEST_SETTINGS` variable. [Link to source.](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Makefile.global#L74)

Comment: And bear in mind that `make test` is, strictly speaking, optional. You can still build from source just fine without it if that was a concern.

Comment: @iainn Yes, I am asking as I had to skip the tests :). Do you know if it is possible to set PHP_TEST_SETTINGS (or better append some) arguments in `./configure`, `make test` command or via env var?

Comment: @Mvorisek Not as far as I can see. You can always echo out the command that executes `run-tests.php` and modify it yourself, you just won't be able to do it via `make test`